# Autofixture Xunit should throw but doesnt

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xunit, autofixture

I'm writing unit tests for my services using autofixture and autodata. This is the test.

```
[Theory]
[AutoMoqData]
public async Task GetByIdAsync_WhenInvalidId_ShouldThrowNotFoundException(
    Mock<IReviewRepository> repositoryMock,
    IReviewService service)
    {
    // Arrange
    repositoryMock.Setup(r => r.GetByIdAsync(It.IsAny<int>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(value: null);

    // Act
    var act = () => service.GetByIdAsync(It.IsAny<int>());

    await act.Should().ThrowAsync<NotFoundException>()
        .WithMessage(ErrorMessages.REVIEW_NOT_FOUND);
        }
```

And this the service method being tested

```
public async Task<Review> GetByIdAsync(int id)
{
    var foundReview = await _repository.GetByIdAsync(id);

    if (foundReview == null)
    {
        Log.Error("Review with id = {@id} not found", id);
        throw new NotFoundException(ErrorMessages.REVIEW_NOT_FOUND);
    }

    return _mapper.Map<Review>(foundReview);
}
```

As you can see, i setup repository used in service to return null if any int is passed so that i can check that the service properly throws my custom exception with my constant error message.
Then i create a delegate of my method and test what i need. But the test fails with message:

```
Message: 
    Expected a <SecondMap.Services.StoreManagementService.BLL.Exceptions.NotFoundException> to be thrown, but no exception was thrown.

  Stack Trace: 
    XUnit2TestFramework.Throw(String message)
    TestFrameworkProvider.Throw(String message)
    DefaultAssertionStrategy.HandleFailure(String message)
    AssertionScope.FailWith(Func`1 failReasonFunc)
    AssertionScope.FailWith(Func`1 failReasonFunc)
    AssertionScope.FailWith(String message)
    DelegateAssertionsBase`2.ThrowInternal[TException](Exception exception, String because, Object[] becauseArgs)
    AsyncFunctionAssertions`2.ThrowAsync[TException](String because, Object[] becauseArgs)
    ExceptionAssertionsExtensions.WithMessage[TException](Task`1 task, String expectedWildcardPattern, String because, Object[] becauseArgs)
    ReviewServiceTests.GetByIdAsync_WhenInvalidId_ShouldThrowNotFoundException(Mock`1 repositoryMock, IReviewService service) line 59
    --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
```

I've tested manually and the method works as expected so I think the problem is with autofixture setups, but cant understand it exactly yet. Here is AutoMoqDataAttribute in case it helps

```
public class AutoMoqDataAttribute : AutoDataAttribute
{
    public AutoMoqDataAttribute() : base(CreateFixture)
    {
            
    }

    private static IFixture CreateFixture()
    {
        var fixture = new Fixture();
        fixture.Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization { ConfigureMembers = true });
        return fixture;
    }
}
```

Comment: So have you debugged into the test to see the value of `foundReview`? That would seem like the logical next step...

Comment: Separately though, `service.GetByIdAsync(It.IsAny<int>());` feels like an odd call in the Act part. I'd expect you to pass an *actual ID*.

Comment: @JonSkeet i've debugged these statements 1) var review = repositoryMock.Object.GetByIdAsync(It.IsAny<int>());
2) var task = service.GetByIdAsync(It.IsAny<int>());. In 1) review is null, which means i've setup the repository GetByIdAsync correctly. In 2) Task.Result is not null and actually is a valid Review model with all the fields filled by AutoFixture. That should confirm that repository used by service and the one i setup are actually different objects, so i tried to apply [Frozen] to them, then to service etc. But still none variant helped.

Comment: `var task = service.GetByIdAsync(It.IsAny<int>());` doesn't appear anywhere in your question. I suggested that you debug into the actual test you've shown - I'd put a break point on your service method, and within that you can see what's going on. (It doesn't help that we don't know how `_repository` is initialized in your service, btw...)

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry for misguidance, i think we misunderstood each a bit, anyways, i solved the question after you gave me a lead with your first comment, thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: solution for TR;DR: change `IService` to `Service`.

**Explanation**: debugging has shown that if you pass interface of the service instead of the actual class, then autofixture will create `Mock<IService>` which will not act the way it is supposed to, so either change `IService` to `Service` or in case you really want to use service you can create customization like that

```
public class AutoMoqDataAttribute : AutoDataAttribute
{
    public AutoMoqDataAttribute() : base(CreateFixture)
    {
    }

    private static IFixture CreateFixture()
    {
        var fixture = new Fixture();
        fixture.Customize(new CompositeCustomization(
            new AutoMoqCustomization { ConfigureMembers = true },
            new ServiceCustomization()));
            return fixture;
    }
}

public class ServiceCustomization : ICustomization
{
    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        fixture.Register<IReviewService>(CreateReviewService);
        fixture.Register<IScheduleService>(CreateScheduleService);
        fixture.Register<IStoreService>(CreateStoreService);
        fixture.Register<IUserService>(CreateUserService);
    }

    private static ReviewService CreateReviewService() => new ReviewService(new Mock<IReviewRepository>().Object, new Mock<IMapper>().Object);

    private static ScheduleService CreateScheduleService() => new ScheduleService(new Mock<IScheduleRepository>().Object, new Mock<IMapper>().Object);

    private static StoreService CreateStoreService() => new StoreService(new Mock<IStoreRepository>().Object, new Mock<IMapper>().Object);

    private static UserService CreateUserService() => new UserService(new Mock<IUserRepository>().Object, new Mock<IMapper>().Object);
}
```

But it really isn't preferable since you want to test actual service